# Rendering multiple document formats with Cocoa's CoreGraphics

Tags: html, cocoa, ms-word, core-graphics, rtf

CoreGraphics gives the possibility to render PDF documents, this is great. But it seems like it could support other types too like Word documents, HTML, RTF and others.

A quick look in the doc2pdf.py example on the Mac OS X Developer DVD makes me think so :

```
  pageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792)
  c = CGPDFContextCreateWithFilename(output_file, pageRect)
  c.beginPage(pageRect)

  if fnmatch(ext,".txt") or fnmatch(ext,".?") or fnmatch(ext,".??"):
    tr = c.drawPlainTextInRect(text, pageRect, font_size)
  elif fnmatch(ext,".rtf"):
    tr = c.drawRTFTextInRect(text, pageRect, font_size)
  elif fnmatch(ext,".htm*") or fnmatch(ext,".php"):
    tr = c.drawHTMLTextInRect(text, pageRect, font_size)
  elif fnmatch(ext,".doc"):
    tr = c.drawDocFormatTextInRect(text, pageRect, font_size)
  elif fnmatch(ext,"*ml"):
    tr = c.drawWordMLFormatTextInRect(text, pageRect, font_size)
  else:
    return "Error: unknown type '%s' for '%s'"%(ext, input_file)
```

Unfortunately, I do not understand how works the CoreGraphics' Python bindings (and it seems that the binding itself is binary and proprietary). I cannot find the C/Obj-C equivalent for these methods in Apple developers documentation. And there is not much webpages found by Google talking about these functionnality.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CoreGraphics alone does this.  The App Kit Addition to the `NSAttributedString` class provides ways to initialize an attributed string from various kinds of documents, and to draw it in the current `NSGraphicsContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I found how it works.

Here's a great Open-Source example here parsing doc, docx, odt, rtf, etc. files only by using Cocoa framework support for these formats : 
http://www.bean-osx.com/Bean.html